# Can you ungroup Custom Fields?

Tags: custom-field, wp-admin

I have been using a lot of Custom Fields to make Wordpress like a CMS, beyond simple posts and post meta. The admin area for adding new posts has little "widgetized" movable areas like the "categories", "publish," and "tags" boxes for instance. With Custom Fields, all are grouped under one "widget" with the same name.

Is there a way to break out the Custom Fields into their own "widget" boxes to rearrange the placement of the admin area?

Comment: How are you creating your Custom Fields?  Are you using a plugin or self-written code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create and position your own meta boxes via `add_meta_box`. You can store the data as meta data behind the scenes but it will allow you to customize the UI in the admin screens.